# Formatting @ (string literal) sign

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, markdown

I noticed that on StackOverflow, a question which used the @ sign to denote a string literal ie

```
string TheClosingQuoteSOULDBeEscaped = @"c:\";
string ButTheSyntaxHighlightingMissesIt = "another string";
```

Doesn't properly handle the string literal and instead thinks the slash at the end of line one is meant to escape the last quote, leading to a mega quote that spans the whole code block.  I saw this in the question listed below:

[Running Command line from an ASPX page, and returning output to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247668/running-command-line-from-an-aspx-page-and-returning-output-to-page)

**EDIT**

The system works!!! The ticket I opened with Google was just [resolved](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=93)!  The project owner, [mikesamuel](http://code.google.com/u/mikesamuel/), fixed it in under four days.  Its in revision 83.  As long as the SO team updates with the next release, this problem is solved.

Comment: This is all Google's fault. I say we march over there and tell them off.

Comment: Oh, does SO use Google for syntax highlighting?  If so, I guess that doesn't bode well for my bug getting fixed.  You don't think they scan forums looking for stuff to do?

Comment: They will if we tell them off enough!

Comment: We're all behind you, Welbog! ...Wayyy behind you.

Comment: @mmyers: Your waffly support will not go unsyrupped.

Comment: +1 for reporting the issue to Google, as indicated in your comment to Jeff.

Comment: Should this be "reopened" or flagged of some sort? Typing `string a = @"dir\"; string b = "hello";` does not work when *I* type it.. :-( Or did google do a rollback for the support of the @-sign?

Comment: bug is still confirmed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this has to be fixed in [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) first.

OK, we just deployed the latest trunk of prettify.js ; revision 83

http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/src/prettify.js

Comment: I opened an issue ticket: http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=93

Comment: Fixed in revision 83 http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?r=83