# Syntax highlighting broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting seems to have been broken recently. For example see the code example at:

[WPF TextBlock Padding is cutting off text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423282/wpf-textblock-padding-is-cutting-off-text)

All the attributes' first letters are black. Is this a bug?

... or a feature?

Comment: i'm pretty sure jeff rolled out the latest release of prettify recently (though I can't find the question where he said it).

Comment: found it, this answer from jeff on 2009-09-29: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/formatting-string-literal-sign/23856#23856

Answer (score 2):

I would classify it as a bug personally because it makes no sense to highlight like that.

Our syntax highlighting is due to the Prettify project, so perhaps this should be taken up with them...unless the team here has managed to fark something up recently with it.

Comment: Since from all appearances the team is in death march mode at the moment (at least until after tomorrow), I'm guess the latter.  But it'll work itself out.

Comment: they rolled out a different prettify version recently, so it's probably a bug in the newer prettify.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/formatting-string-literal-sign/23856#23856

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to wait for the next public release of [google prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/). I don't see one up there yet, only the trunk copy.

Meta users asked me to put in the latest prettify, I did, and now meta users are complaining about it.

So in the future, no updates until prettify has a public release.

OK, I deployed the latest prettify (no public release in sight, so the trunk.)