# Still not-fixed bug: literal string

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

to bring [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/formatting-string-literal-sign) to the front, as it clearly got lost or was reintroduced to google-code-prettify

Still Literal Strings will highlight the rest of the code as String, see this screenshot:

[image: StringLiteral Error]

in the question referenced there is the answer, that this should have been fixed with code-prettify upgrade, but as it is clearly still not that way, i hereby ask this question:

Why is the codeblock highlighted as Strign after the String Literal?

Comment: Can you link to the post with that code?

Comment: There is no bug. The case you describe is result of not telling the prettify what language to use, so it has to guess and simply fails in guessing. Adding language tag will "fix" this problem. For example I've just added [tag:c#] tag [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14859940/447356) and prettify works just fine. You can also force specific code block to specific pretty language by adding `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` above it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Good call. Same thing worked on [delete option on fineuploader](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17292898/1288).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Bill already found it...

Comment: Found what? He used my tip that's all.