# Markdown parser issue for C# verbatim string literal

Tags: support, markdown

The bug described in [Formatting @ (string literal) sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23851/formatting-string-literal-sign) is back (or was never gone?).

Seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23899574/879553 (first snippet)

Comment: For some reason the tag didn't "catch", forcing the C# language via `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` solved this. It's OK now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is there are two tags on the question which have syntax highlighting enabled:

- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) uses lang-cs
- [sql-server-2008](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008) uses lang-sql

In a case where there are conflicting languages, everything reverts to default and Prettify is allowed to try and infer what language is actually being used. Thus, you are required to explicitly indicate the language if it gets it wrong.